# I can't make a hammer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tinkers-construct

I made all the hammer parts and I went to the tool station and I looked for hammer and it did not come up so did the excavator 
Please
Help me!

Answer (score 4):

The Tool Station:

[image: Tool station]

Is used only to make basic tools, like shovels, swords etc. To create advanced tools like the hammer or excavator you need a Tool *Forge*:

[image: Tool Forge]

Which is crafted with 4 blocks of metal (pretty much any metal as long as they're all the same, seared bricks and a tool station, crafted like this:

```
S S S
M T M
M   M
```

With S being seared bricks, M being metal blocks and T being the tool station.

Comment: Okay,I'll take that advice.